# How to use exportRecordsTyped function from the redcapAPI package to import the data without factors?

Tags: r, import, factors, redcap

I had previously used the following code to import data from REDCap:

```
data.df <- redcapAPI::exportRecords(rcon, 
                             forms = c("setup_log"),
                             labels = FALSE, 
                             factors = FALSE)
```

Because the exportRecords function is deprecated, I would like to use the new exportRecordsTyped function from the redcapAPI package. However, it seems to import all the strings as factors, which I do not want: the rest of my code relies on them not being factors.

I have been looking through the help page for exportRecordsTyped, but I have not found a way to import all the columns not as factors. I would like something like factors = FALSE, which does not seem to exist in the new exportRecordsTyped. Is there a way that I can do this?

I have found a way to do this with the REDCapR package redcap_read_oneshot function as follows, but I am still wondering if there is a way to do this with exportRecordsTyped.

```
data.df <- REDCapR::redcap_read_oneshot(Redcap.url,
                                        Redcap.token,
                                        forms = c("setup_log"),
                                        verbose = FALSE
                                        )$data
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative package for the redcap API: [`REDCapR`](https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/). Its function `redcap_read_oneshot()` does not convert strings to factors.

```
rc_data <- 
  redcap_read_oneshot(
  redcap_uri = "https://<url/ip to your redcap instance here>/api/",
  token = "your redcap API key here")

rc_data$data
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had just found this myself and was editing my question to include this function when I saw your answer. I was hoping to still find a way to use exportRecordsTyped if possible, but it may not be.

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE

with the release of version 2.8.0, this can be accomplished by using

```
exportRecordsTyped(rcon, 
                   cast = default_cast_no_factor)
```

### Previous answer

Some options:

#### Post Processing

The fastest way to get what you want is probably

```
X <- exportRecordsTyped(rcon)

factor_cols <- vapply(X, is.factor, logical(1))
X[factor_cols] <- lapply(X[factor_cols], as.character)
```

Another alternative would be to use `recastRecords`

```
X <- exportRecordsTyped(rcon) |>
  recastRecords(rcon, 
             cast = list(dropdown = as.character, 
                         radio = as.character, 
                         checkbox = as.character, 
                         yesno = as.character))
```

but that's a lot of typing if you need to do that regularly.

#### Define your own casting functions

You can also define some overrides that return the character vectors instead of the factors.

```
castLabelCharacter <- function(x, field_name, coding){
  code_match <- getCodingIndex(x, coding)
  
  unname(coding[code_match])
}

castCheckedCharacter <- function(x, field_name, coding){
  checked_value <- getCheckedValue(coding, field_name)
  
  x_checked <- x %in% checked_value 
  
  c("Unchecked", "Checked")[(x_checked)+1]
}
```

And then

```
exportRecordsTyped(rcon, 
    cast = list(dropdown = castLabelCharacter, 
                 radio = castLabelCharacter, 
                 checkbox = castCheckedCharacter)
```

#### Redefine the provided casting functions

Lastly, you can change the definition of the casting functions before calling `exportRecordsTyped`

```
castLabel <- function(x, field_name, coding){
  code_match <- getCodingIndex(x, coding)
  
  unname(coding[code_match])
}

castChecked <- function(x, field_name, coding){
  checked_value <- getCheckedValue(coding, field_name)
  
  x_checked <- x %in% checked_value 
  
  c("Unchecked", "Checked")[(x_checked)+1]
}
```

This overwrites the behavior of the casting functions within your session and would need to be run each time you load `redcapAPI`.